# Как записать Python объект в html?

Tags: html, python, массивы

```
<tbody>

{% for i in answer.total %}
    <tr class="" data-object-id="7278d818-acd4-442d-af65-fa7c3b9e81e6" id="project_usage__row__7278d818-acd4-442d-af65-fa7c3b9e81e6">
      <td class="sortable anchor normal_column">{{ answer.total.inst_id }}</td>
      <td class="sortable normal_column"></td>
      <td class="sortable normal_column"></td>
      <td class="sortable normal_column"></td>
      <td class="sortable normal_column"><span data-seconds="1176">19&nbsp;minutes</span></td>


    </tr>
{% endfor %}

</tbody>
```

`Total` является объектом с массивами, в котором объекты `project_id`, `inst_id`, `totaltime`.

Цель: записать каждую `project_id`, `inst_id`, `totaltime` в отдельный столбец.

Как вписать в столбец?  `{answer.total.inst_id}` - Думала так нужно, но ничего не записывает.

Comment: Во-первых посмотрите, как работает `for-in` цикл, все последующие обращение по логике должны происходить через переменную `i` как `i.inst_id`. Во-вторых, не совсем понятна структура ваших переменных. Вы говорите, что `inst_id` - массив, а обращаетесь с ним как с переменной поля объекта без индексов. Приведите чуть более подробный пример структуры `total`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ясненько, судя по структуре, у Вас в total еще один массив и в нем уже исходные данные. Попробуйте двойной цикл тогда так:

```
 {% for child in answer.total %}
    {% for i in child %}

     <tr class="" data-object-id="7278d818-acd4-442d-af65-fa7c3b9e81e6" id="project_usage__row__7278d818-acd4-442d-af65-fa7c3b9e81e6">
        <td class="sortable anchor normal_column">{{ i.inst_id }}</td>
        <td class="sortable normal_column"></td>
        <td class="sortable normal_column"></td>
        <td class="sortable normal_column"></td>
        <td class="sortable normal_column"><span data-seconds="1176">19&nbsp;minutes</span></td>
     </tr>

    {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

P.S. А еще я буду рад, если кто-то мне подскажет, как вставить многостраничный код в комментарий, а то вариант с отступами что-то у меня не работает ^_^

Comment: сделалась большая таблица с столько строками сколько inst_id.
{{ i.child }} всеравно ничего не выводит, таблица пустая ((

Comment: просто {{ child }}  выводит  project_id

Comment: Тогда выведите без циклов свой {{ answer.total }} на распечатку. У меня такое ощущение, что в нем просто напросто нет того, что вы хотите от него сейчас получить. Если под ответом p2mbot вы уже привели всю распечатку, то так оно и есть и у Вас где-то ошибка на уровне передачи модели данных вашему представлению.

Comment: Работает так как вы написали, просто все объекты надо было внести в один массив, иначе for цикл не срабатывает.

Comment: `P.S. А еще я буду рад, если кто-то мне подскажет, как вставить многостраничный код в комментарий, а то вариант с отступами что-то у меня не работает ^_^` — в комментариях markdown урезанный. Кажется, никак нельзя.

Comment: @Zelta, никак, потому что не надо писать в комментариях код. Добавьте его в ответ, если требуется.

Comment: @Nofate, тут я не согласен, но правила есть правила.

Comment: @Nofate, жаль, в редких случаях его очень не хватает для добавления уточняющих комментариев с 2-3 строками кода, которые никак не являются ответом.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот код:

```
<tbody>

{% for i in answer.total %}
    <tr class="" data-object-id="7278d818-acd4-442d-af65-fa7c3b9e81e6" id="project_usage__row__7278d818-acd4-442d-af65-fa7c3b9e81e6">
      <td class="sortable anchor normal_column">{{ i.inst_id }}</td>
      <td class="sortable normal_column"></td>
      <td class="sortable normal_column"></td>
      <td class="sortable normal_column"></td>
      <td class="sortable normal_column"><span data-seconds="1176">19&nbsp;minutes</span></td>


    </tr>
{% endfor %}

</tbody>
```

Внутри цикла к переменной надо обращаться так как вы ее обозначили, как `i`

Comment: пусто. Не выводит ничего. Может я могу показать Python фрагмент где идентифицированы обьекты?

Comment: @Lera а Вы уверены, что `total` вообще содержит данные?

Comment: да. Он выводит следующие: {'total': {'c56f75091edc4480a204e5549ef11664': {'84da2155-792d-4066-bee3-7cce4df82ce9': {'totaltime_1': [520L]}, '1088ca15-88e0-47c6-ab52-2e63b23ae3ba': {'totaltime_1': [1L]}}}}

Answer (score 0):

```
{'total': {'c56f75091edc4480a204e5549ef11664': {'84da2155-792d-4066-bee3-7cce4df82ce9': {'totaltime_1': [520L]}, '1088ca15-88e0-47c6-ab52-2e63b23ae3ba': {'totaltime_1': [1L]}}}}
```

Вот эту информацию следовало добавить в сам вопрос. Я так понимаю, это содержание `answer`, а не `total`? Тогда нам нужно разложить данные в более подходящий для `for` формат. Ключ первого поколения это и есть `project_id`? Будем считать так, для начала. Потом, если будет нужно, обновлю ответ.

```
{% for i in chain(*map(lambda x: map(lambda y: (x[0], y[0], y[1]['totaltime_1'][0]), x[1].items()), answer.total.items())) %}

     <tr class="" data-object-id="7278d818-acd4-442d-af65-fa7c3b9e81e6" id="project_usage__row__7278d818-acd4-442d-af65-fa7c3b9e81e6">
        <td class="sortable anchor normal_column">{{ loop.index }}</td>
        <td class="sortable normal_column">{{ i[0] }}</td>
        <td class="sortable normal_column">{{ i[1] }}</td>
        <td class="sortable normal_column">{{ i[2] }}</td>
        <td class="sortable normal_column"><span data-seconds="1176">19&nbsp;minutes</span></td>
     </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

Тестировал с приведёнными данными на втором питоне. На третьем не уверен как будет работать. Возможно, что нормально.

**UPD**:
А, есть проблема. Функция `chain` — не `built-in`. Это значит, что по-умолчанию из среды jinja2 она доступна не будет. Решить это можно несколькими способами. Самый простой — делать обработку данных до передачи в jinja2.

```
from itertools import chain
# Это должно быть где-нибудь в начале .py-файла, вместе с другими импортами

def foobar():
    return render_template('template.html', answer_total=chain(*map(lambda x: map(lambda y: (x[0], y[0], y[1]['totaltime_1'][0]), x[1].items()), answer.total.items())))
# Это должно быть в вашем контроллере. Здесь я привёл возвратную функцию из Flask, но она может иметь и другой формат. Главное — совершать обработку answer_total именно здесь, в .py-файле, а в темплэйт отправлять уже готовые к for данные.
```

Можно для удобства представить всю эту хрень как функцию, чтобы контроллер не засирать, и чтоб её потом легко было при необходимости перекинуть в модель:

```
rework_stupid_structure = lambda q: chain(*map(lambda x: map(lambda y: (x[0], y[0], y[1]['totaltime_1'][0]), x[1].items()), q.items()))

# Теперь наш контроллер может выглядеть более-менее прилично:
def foobar():
    return render_template('template.html', answer_total=rework_stupid_structure(answer.total))
```

Второй способ, более навороченный — прокинуть функцию `chain` в Jinja2. Для этого смотрите [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036082/call-a-python-function-from-jinja2) ответ.